# Create instances from variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to come up with a class that allows multiple types to be created via variadic template arguments, but I get errors during compilation:

http://ideone.com/nDWBET

```
#include <list>
#include <memory>

struct IBaseType
{
};

class Type1 : public IBaseType
{
};

class Type2 : public IBaseType
{
};

template <typename... T>
class CreateTypes
{
public:
    CreateTypes()
    {
        [](...){ }((m_types.push_back(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T())))...);
    }

private:
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<IBaseType>> m_types;
};

int main()
{
    CreateTypes<Type1, Type2> createTypes;
    return 0;
}
```

> prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘CreateTypes::CreateTypes() [with T = {Type1, Type2}]’:
>   prog.cpp:31:28: required from here
>   prog.cpp:22:9: error: invalid use of void expression

What's the solution for this? Or is there an alternative approach that I can take?

Comment: Wondering... Clang fails to compile it with segfault.

Comment: I'm using Clang in Xcode and it fails to compile with the use of `std::unique_ptr`, but compiles fine with raw pointers.

Comment: "If however, I change the list to be `std::list<IBaseType*>` and the lambda to be `m_types.push_back(new T())` it works fine." => Huh? I still get the error with this code: http://ideone.com/wuMyBj (did I miss something?)

Comment: Weird, I'm getting the error now as well. I'll retract that statement about raw pointers working.
http://ideone.com/nDWBET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ForEveR and Xeo gave me the answers I was looking for, but I had to adapt their solutions slightly as Clang wouldn't execute the code of the empty lambda (I assume it was optimised away, even in debug). Here's my final solution (which incorporates a runtime check to ensure the right number of types is always created):

```
template <typename... Types>
struct VariadicTemplateCount
{
    static const size_t value = sizeof...(Types);
};

// ..............

CreateTypes()
{
    struct ShutTheCompiler
    {
        static void Up(const int[])
        {
        }
    };

    const int creation[] = {0, (m_types.push_back(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T())), 0)... };
    ShutTheCompiler::Up(creation);
    ASSERT(m_types.size() == VariadicTemplateCount<Types...>::value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is, that `push_back` returns void. You can try to use `insert`

```
[](...) { }((m_types.insert(m_types.end(), std::unique_ptr<T>(new T())), 0)...);
```

from comments:
with 0 `push_back` will work too.

```
[](...) { }((m_types.push_back(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T())), 0)...);
```

Comment: Marvelous. That works in ideone, but not in Clang (Xcode). Why does push_back work for raw pointers but not smart pointer?

Comment: @MarkIngram work for me with clang 3.2 on Ubuntu. You code with change unique_ptr to T* give crash on clang and compile error about void type in gcc.

Comment: Sorry, take that comment back, it does build in Clang, I'd forgotten to change the list back from raw pointer to smart pointer. Why does push_back work for raw pointers though?

Comment: @MarkIngram don't know. Not compile for me. Am i doing something wrong? http://ideone.com/SRPGAU

Comment: Ellipsis (C-style varargs) require trivial types, and the iterator returned from `insert` has a high chance of not being trivial. Use `(insert_expr, 0)`.

Comment: @ForEveR Weird, I'm getting the error now as well. I'll retract that statement about raw pointers working.
http://ideone.com/nDWBET

Comment: Using the comma operator allows the push_back method to work now. Thanks @Xeo and ForEveR.

Comment: @MarkIngram look at the comment of Xeo. Both expression are evaluated, but result is last expression.

Comment: Nice, C++ looking more cryptic with every passing day ;) I'd like to mention, that if the order of elements in the list is important, you'll have to go with a recursive solution here.

Comment: @catscradle: Or use list-initialization (for example `int tmp[] = {0, (expr, 0)...}` - the extra `0` if the variadic pack is empty).

Comment: @Xeo The ordering of the list is important to my app. Is there a solution to this that doesn't involve a temporary variable?

Comment: I've done @Xeo's solution, but without the variable:
`[](...){ }({ 0, (m_types.push_back(std::make_unique<Types>()), 0)... });`

Comment: I'm not sure if an `std::initializer_list<int>` counts as trivial for the purpose of the ellipsis. FWIW, what I usually do `using swallow = int[]; swallow{0, (expr, 0)...};`.

Comment: @Xeo, I'm not sure why, but Clang seems to optimise away the whole line. I have to assign it to a variable - `int creation[] = {0, (expr, 0)...};`.

Comment: @MarkIngram that seems fixed in my current trunk snapshot.

Comment: @Mark: I'm pretty sure such an optimization is disallowed if `expr` contains side-effects.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes / Xeo I'm using Clang 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) in Xcode 4.6.2.